# Return top 10 most frequently occurring values from an alphanumerical list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of postcodes and zipcodes – a series of alphanumerical values.

I need to return the top 10 most frequently occurring postcodes from the list.

Here's the data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m7v_EkPDXnbUL_Qbp0B3sjq0eyebqJyasOymbtnmulY/edit?usp=sharing

Here's a sample:

```
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
e1
e1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E1
E10
E10
E10
E10
E10
E10
e10
E11
E11
E11
E11
E11
E11
E11
E11
E11
E11
E11
E12
E12
E13
E13
E13
E13
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
e14
E14
E14
E14
E14
E14
e14
e14
E14
E15
E15
E15
E15
E15
E15
E15
E15
E15
E15
E15
E15
e15
E15
E15
E15
E1
E16
E16
E16
E16
E16
E16
E16
E16
E16
E1
E1
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E17
E18
E18
E18
E18
E19
E1W
E1W
E1W
E1W
E1W
E1W
E2
E2 0
E2
E2
e2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
e2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
e2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2 7
E2 7
E2 7
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
E2
e2
E2
E2
E2.
E20
E20
E20
E20
e2
e2
E28
E2
e2
E3
e3
E3
E3
e3
e3
e3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
e3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
e3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E3
E4
E4
E4L
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
e5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
E5
e5
e5
E5
e5
e5
E5
E5
E7
E7
E7
E7
E7
E7
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
e8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8 3
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
E8
e8
E8
E8
e8
E8
E8
E8
e8
e8
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
e9
E9
E9
e9
E9
E9
E9
e9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
E9
e9
E9
E98
EC@A
EC1 Y
EC14
EC1A
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1M
EC1N
EC1N
EC1N
EC1N
EC1N
EC1N
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1R
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1V
EC1Y
EC1Y
EC1Y
EC1Y
EC1Y
EC2
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2A
EC2M
EC2M
ec2v
EC2Y
EC2Y
EC2Y
EC2Y
EC2Y
EC2Y
EC2Y
EC2Y
EC2Y
EC3N
EC4A
EC4A
EC4A
EC4A
EC4V
EC4V
EC4V
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH1
EH11
EH12
EH15
EH2
EH2
EH3
EH3
eh33
eh33
EH4
EH4
EH4
EH6
EH6
EH6
EH7
EH8
EH8
EH8
EH9
```

For example, I would want results like

- `E2`                (because it occurs 170 times)
- `E8`                (because it occurs 97 times)
- ⋮

Any suggestions very much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please include sample code **in the question**. Most people will not download spreadsheets from unknown locations.

Comment: what do you mean top 10, occurring most often, or at the beginning if ordered? Have you tried to use a pivot table?

Comment: Yes i mean the 10 most occurring. Have not tried a pivot table - not used one before.

Comment: I have not posted the data as it its a large set - the link is safe - it's just a google sheet.

Comment: Here are three suggestions: When you ask a question, (1) say what you mean.  If asked for clarification, [edit] the question to clarify it; don't just respond in a comment.  (2) Construct an example that can fit into 25 lines or less.  I realize that, in a list of 25 values with more than ten unique, you're pretty much constrained to frequency distributions of 2 and 3 — so say "For example, the top **five** of the following ..."  (3) Show the output you want for your example data.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the intervention scott! really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sanitize your data because the same zipcode could appear sometimes on uppercase and sometimes on lowercase, according to the sample you sent. After that you can do this:

1. Go to *Data -> Sort* and sort by the column of the zipcodes, so same zipcodes are consecutive. If the first cell of the column is a Title then check in the dialog box *My data has headers*. If you don't have a header / title then after sorting insert a row on row 1 and put one.
2. Click on *Data -> Subtotal* and in the Dialog Box choose the title of your column of zipcodes and in function choose *Count*. Press OK.
3. On the left side of the sheet you will find a hierarchy with button 1,2 and 3. Press 2 so you see only the subtotals. That is the count of each zipcode.
4. On the menu go to *Home -> Find & Select -> Go To Special*. In dialog box select *Visible Cells Only*. Copy and Paste on other worksheet.
5. On the new worksheet Go to *Data -> Ungroup*  to break the hierarchy and then sort by the column of values.